# Using java.util.TimeZone to get current time for a particular timezone

Tags: java, datetime, coldfusion

I am creating a ColdFusion Application that needs to display the current time in in a number
of timezones and was wondering if anyone could tell me how to do this using `java.util.TimeZone` ?

What I have currently is assembled from different posts/articles :

```
<cfset timezoneClass = createObject( "java", "java.util.TimeZone" ) />
<cfset pragueZoneId = "Europe/Prague" />
<cfset pragueTimezone = timezoneClass.getTimeZone(javaCast( "string", pragueZoneId )) />
<cfset pragueCalendar = createObject( "java", "java.util.GregorianCalendar" ).init(pragueTimezone) />
```

I just don't know how to apply the above to get the current time for the timezone.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include this line of code at the top of the above code: <cfset timezoneClass = createObject( "java", "java.util.TimeZone" ) />

Comment: You can edit your post, you don't have to add corrections as comments.

Comment: I would look at using [JODA](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for any time converting.  It adds a little overhead to the project but is more advaced than the standard JAVA timezone information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a Java `SimpleDateFormat` object and configure it with the desired format you want to display the date/time.  Then you can extract the `Date` from the `GregorianCalendar` using its `getTime()` method and pass this value to `SimpleDateFormat` to produce a `String` that you can display.

A second variant is be to use method `String.format()` using a format string and the result of `getTime()`.

Alternatively, you can use method `toString()` of the `GregorianCalendar` object, but this is not recommended.

Comment: @AlanJames  Very glad to hear that. :-)